# Python execute file is not a valid Win32 application on Windows 2000

Tags: python, pyinstaller, windows-2000

I am using Win7 (64 bit) to create simple Python script as “helloworld.py” then create executable file by using PyInstaller as command “pyinstaller helloworld.py --onefile”. helloworld.exe is created under “dist” folder. After that, I tried to test it by using DOS command line "call helloworld.exe". It shows good result “helloworld” message as expectation.
Then I copied helloworld.exe to my target machine Windows 2000 and call helloworld.exe to test it but found the error dialog with message “C:\dist\helloworld.exe is not a valid Win32 application.”
Anyone can help to advise me to fix this problem?

Python3.8.8 (32 bit)
PyInstaller4.2

Comment: Python doesn't even support windows XP any more these days (for good reason) - hell I think win7 support just ran out as well. You'll need an ancient python install to run on win2k. I wouldn't count on any py3  version from run on there honestly.

Comment: thank you very much Voo, Looks like I have to find another programing language that can be used for Windows 2000